# R subset exclusion based on string creates extra column

Tags: r, string, subset, rows

I have a data set as such below

```
salaries <- read.csv('salaries.csv', header=TRUE)
print(salaries)

Name    Job         Salary  CompanyExperience   IndustryExperience
John    Engineer    50000       3               12
Adam    Manager     55000       6               7
Alice   Manager     #N/A        6               6
Bob     Engineer    65000       5               #N/A
Carl    Engineer    70000       #N/A            10
```

I would like to plot some of this information, however I would need to exclude any data points with "#N/A" by removing any rows where there is an "#N/A" text string (produced by MS Excel spreadsheet exported to CSV) to make a plot of Salary ~ CompanyExperience.
My code to subset is as follows:

```
salaries <-salaries[salaries$CompanyExperience!="#N/A" & 
salaries$Salary!="#N/A",]
#write.csv(salaries, "salaries2.csv")
#salaries <- read.csv('salaries2.csv', header=TRUE)
print(salaries)
```

Now this seems to work without any issue, producing:

```
  Name      Job Salary     CompanyExperience     IndustryExperience
1 John Engineer  50000                 3                 12
2 Adam  Manager  55000                 6                  7
4  Bob Engineer  65000                 5               #N/A
```

Which seems fine, however as soon as I try to put this data subset into a linear regression, I get an error:

```
> salarylinear <- lm(salaries$CompanyExperience ~ salaries$Salary)
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Now if I've done some experimenting and have found that if I subset the data using things like "!=10000" or "<50", I dont get this error. Also, I've found that when I write this new subset into a CSV file and read it again (by removing the # tags in the code above, the data set will have added a mysterious "X" column at the front and wont have the error when trying to run a linear regression:

```
  X Name      Job     Salary     CompanyExperience     IndustryExperience
1 1 John     Engineer  50000                 3                 12
2 2 Adam     Manager   55000                 6                  7
3 4 Bob      Engineer  65000                 5               #N/A
```

I've searched the web and cant find any reason why this is happening. Is there a way I can produce a useable subset by excluding "#N/A" strings without having to resort to writing the data to disk and reading into memory again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is that columns of data that you think are numeric are not in fact numeric. Two things are leading to this:

1. `read.csv()` doesn't know that "#N/A" means "missing" and as a result, it is reading in "#N/A" as a string (not a number), causing it to think that the whole columns of Salary, CompanyExperience, and IndustryExperience are string variables.
2. `read.csv()` has a notorious default to read in strings as factors. If you're unfamiliar with factors, one good resource is [this](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html).

This combination of events is why `lm()` thinks your dependent variable is a factor and is throwing an error.

The solution is to add `na.strings = "#N/A"` as an argument to `read.csv()`. Then your data will be read in as numeric. You can proceed straight to running your regression because `lm()` will drop rows with NA's automatically.

However, to be a bit more explicit, you may also want to add `stringsAsFactors =  FALSE` as an argument to `read.csv()` just in case you have any other things that mean "missing" but are coded as, say, a blank. And, if you want to handle the NAs manually before running your regression, you can drop rows with NAs using `complete.cases()` or something like `salaries[!is.na(Salary),]`

Comment: I experimented with the code "Salaries <-Salaries[!is.na(Salaries),]" and found that it adds a whole bunch of "NA" and then "NA.1" through to "NA.16" rows to the data frame (full of "NA" entries that don't produce errors with the lm() thankfully). This results in a data frame of 22 rows plus header.
The other approach of "Salaries <-Salaries[complete.cases(Salaries), ]" doesn't do this and simply excludes the rows so I get a data frame of 2 rows plus header (the intended effect).
I'm new to R and don't quite understand how the first example includes the whole lot of bogus rows?

Comment: What you are trying to do is to select a subset of rows.  The simplest expression to do this is something like `mydf[myvec, ]` where `myvec` contains `TRUE` for rows that should be kept in the subset and `FALSE` for rows that should be dropped.  Notice the difference between your two attempts at subsetting:  `complete.cases()` returns a _vector_ and that vector is the same length as the number of rows in your data.frame; this is what you want.  `!(is.na())` returns a _matrix_ with the same dimensions as your data.frame; _not_ what you want.

Comment: But !is.na() is returning a matrix with different (larger) dimensions than my data.frame, which is what confuses me. This is what I mean https://imgur.com/a/X6cDxhA here.

Comment: I will post a new "answer" with an example to show you what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up to our discussion in the comments about what happens when you subset a data.frame with a matrix:

First, we create a 3x2 dataframe to work with:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6)
```

Then, let's create a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` for the rows we want to keep when we subset our dataframe.

```
v <- c(T,T,F)
```

Here, `v` has 2 `TRUE`s followed by 1 `FALSE` so if we subset our 3-row dataframe with `v`, we will be selecting the first 2 rows and omitting the 3rd row:

```
df[v,]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
```

Great, that works as expected.  But what about if we subset with a matrix? We create matrix `m` that has the same 3x2 dimensions as our dataframe. `m` is full of `TRUE`s except for 2 `FALSE`s in cells (1,1) and (3,2).

```
m <- matrix(c(F,T,T,T,T,F), ncol=2)
m
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, if we try to subset our dataframe with `m`, we might at first think that we're gong to only get row 2 back, because `m` has a `FALSE` in its first and third row. That, of course, isn't what happens.

```
df[m,]
      x  y
2     2  5
3     3  6
NA   NA NA
NA.1 NA NA
```

The trick to understanding this is to know that a matrix in R is just a vector with a dimension attribute.  The dimension is as expected, because we created `m`:

```
dim(m)
[1] 3 2
```

But as a vector, what does `m` look like:

```
as.vector(m)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

We see that `m`-as-a-vector is just the columns of `m`, repeated one after the other (because R "fills in" matrices column-wise).  Let me re-write `m` with the original cells identified, in case my description isn't clear:

```
[1] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
    (1,1)   (2,1)  (3,1)  (1,2)  (2,2)  (3,2)
```

So when we try to subset our dataframe with `m`, it's like using this length-6 vector, and this length-6 vector says to select rows 2:5.  So when we write `df[m, ]` R faithfully selects rows 2 and 3, and then when it tries to select rows 4 and 5, they don't "exist" so R fills them in with `NA`s. This is why we get *more* rows in our subset than in our original dataframe.

Lastly, we saw that `df[m, ]` has funny rownames like `NA.1`. Rownames must be unique, so R calls the row 4 of the "subset" 'NA' and it calls row 5 of the subset 'NA.1'.

I hope this clears it up for you.  Happy coding!